# Style Background Url Image For IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have trouble with background url on hover in IE8.

For the other browsers and IE9 it works fine, but in IE8 the problem is following:

The original image is showing with the image which shows on hover in there.

When i do mouse hover the image is showing but the original image is over there.

Exists anyway to solved this??

**CSS:**

```
#toTop {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:10px; 
    right:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    z-index:99999;
    background:transparent url('original.png') no-repeat;
    background-size:58px 59px;
    width:58px;
    height:59px;
}

#toTop:hover{
    background:url('hover.png') no-repeat;
    background-size:213px 59px;
    width:213px;
    height:59px;
}

html > body div#toTop {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
    src='original.png',
    sizingMethod='scale');
}

html > body div#toTop:hover{
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
    src='hover.png',
    sizingMethod='scale');
}
```

I use the css IE8 selector to save the width and height which i define above.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle url to test it?

Comment: @Apostolos will jsfiddle work with IE8?

Comment: it is just for testing whats wrong there :)

Comment: @abhitalks - jsFiddle's editor doesn't work in IE8, but you can view the results page just fine. Or you can use jsBin instead if you need a tool with an editor that works in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

> You have to check your doctype. Replace it with your loader doctype.
>   In Quirks Mode, IE older version not support ":hover" on elements well, other than " tag".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

> If you like you can know about standard and Quriks mode [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode)

Comment: +1 for Quirks mode mention. The Op's code works well even in IE7, but will fail in quirks mode!

Comment: @abhitalks thanks, yes you are right, It's very important topic and without taking precautions things goes wrong with design. specially with IE.